# XML to LINQ how to take exact informations?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to extract some information from the xml sample below. I want to pull out a collection of rows that contain a column I'm interested in.

I dont really know how to do that... I tried this code, but it didnt work:

```
    XElement elem = XElement.Load("SIMC.xml");
    var homePhone = from phoneno in elem.Elements("row")
                    where (string)phoneno.Element("col").Attribute("name") == "NAZWA"
                    select phoneno;
   // Console.WriteLine("List HomePhone Nos.");
    foreach (XElement xEle in homePhone)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(xEle.Element("col").Value);
    }
```

Here's a sample of the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teryt>
<catalog name="SIMC" type="all" date="2015-01-01">
<row>
<col name="WOJ">18</col>
<col name="POW">16</col>
<col name="GMI">13</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">2</col>
<col name="RM">00</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Na Polu</col>
<col name="SYM">0664326</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0664310</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">28</col>
<col name="POW">06</col>
<col name="GMI">05</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">2</col>
<col name="RM">03</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Majerka</col>
<col name="SYM">0761615</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0761609</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">12</col>
<col name="POW">09</col>
<col name="GMI">03</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">5</col>
<col name="RM">00</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Pod Kamiennikiem</col>
<col name="SYM">0328485</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0328456</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">32</col>
<col name="POW">17</col>
<col name="GMI">04</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">5</col>
<col name="RM">01</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Miłogoszcz</col>
<col name="SYM">0530732</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0530732</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
```

I want to extract row elements where there is a column with attribute `name` equal to `NAZWA` and column value `Miłogoszcz`.

My code shows nothing at the moment

Comment: Please do not use links to external sources to support your question. They can (and often do) become out of date or just plain missing, rendering the question itself useless to future readers. Please do provide a _short_ example of the XML format in your question, so that the question is entirely self-contained. Also, please be more specific than "it didn't work". Explain clearly what the code you tried did, and how that was different from what you expected or wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we think about this problem intuitively what we really want is this:

> Return rows where there is any column in that row that has an attribute 'name' with a specific value and a column value with a specific value.

Let's assume that we've already got our `IEnumerable<XElement> rows` that represents the row elements of the XML file. We could then select only the rows we care about by using LINQ's extension methods. Here's what one such function might look like.

```
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetRowsWithColumn(IEnumerable<XElement> rows, String name, String value) 
    {
        return rows
            .Where(row => row.Elements("col") //Get Columns
                .Any(col => //This column should...
                    col.Attributes("name").Any(attr => attr.Value.Equals(name)) //have the right name attribute
                    && col.Value.Equals(value))); //and have the right value
    }
```

Here is a complete program that I believe does what you're asking. It opens up the file and then explores the elements, returning rows where there is a sub-element "col" that has an attribute name with value `NAZWA` and that column has a value `Miłogoszcz`

This code uses the function we wrote above so you can plug in whatever you like for the column name attribute and the value of the column.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace StackOverflowTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetRowsWithColumn(IEnumerable<XElement> rows, String name, String value) 
        {
            return rows
                .Where(row => row.Elements("col")
                    .Any(col =>
                        col.Attributes("name").Any(attr => attr.Value.Equals(name))
                        && col.Value.Equals(value)));
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load file
            XElement elem = XElement.Load("./test.xml");

            //Get Rows
            var rows = elem
                .Elements("catalog")
                .Elements("row");

            //Filter rows
            var interestingRows = GetRowsWithColumn(rows, "NAZWA", "Miłogoszcz");

            //Print rows
            foreach (var row in interestingRows)
            {
                //This is MessageBox.Show in your example
                Console.WriteLine(row);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that solves your problem. Let me know if I missed anything.

Please note that I did change your XML file to be valid by including closing blocks for the top-level elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teryt>
<catalog name="SIMC" type="all" date="2015-01-01">
<row>
<col name="WOJ">18</col>
<col name="POW">16</col>
<col name="GMI">13</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">2</col>
<col name="RM">00</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Na Polu</col>
<col name="SYM">0664326</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0664310</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">28</col>
<col name="POW">06</col>
<col name="GMI">05</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">2</col>
<col name="RM">03</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Majerka</col>
<col name="SYM">0761615</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0761609</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">12</col>
<col name="POW">09</col>
<col name="GMI">03</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">5</col>
<col name="RM">00</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Pod Kamiennikiem</col>
<col name="SYM">0328485</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0328456</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="WOJ">32</col>
<col name="POW">17</col>
<col name="GMI">04</col>
<col name="RODZ_GMI">5</col>
<col name="RM">01</col>
<col name="MZ">1</col>
<col name="NAZWA">Miłogoszcz</col>
<col name="SYM">0530732</col>
<col name="SYMPOD">0530732</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
</catalog>
</teryt>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use `Descendents` or walk the XML hierarchy correctly, you are skipping over two levels in your logic. I also changed the `(string)` to `.Value` to work correctly.

```
XElement elem = XElement.Load("SIMC.xml");
var homePhone = from phoneno in elem.Elements("teryt")
                                    .Elements("catalog")
                                    .Elements("row")
                where phoneno.Elements("col")
                             .Any(xelm =>
                                      xelm.Attribute("name").Value == "NAZWA" &&
                                      xelm.Value == "Miłogoszcz")
                select phoneno;
// Console.WriteLine("List HomePhone Nos.");
foreach (XElement xEle in homePhone)
{
    //Note that you need to decide how to format this
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ",
                    xEle.Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value + "=" + x.Value));
}
```

Comment: And where should I place exact nazwa like "Na Polu", to get informations about row which contains "Na Polu"? Thank you for help ;)

Comment: @PiotrBagier: Updated, note that "displaying the whole row" is another issue, since you didn't detail how you wanted it to look, so I just outputted the original `<row>` in its raw form for now.

Comment: I parsed it into string, but as a result I still cant get messagebox with informations :(

Comment: @PiotrBagier: I added a sample, but honestly you may want to skip the message box step and look instead at what final result you want. If you need to ensure the correct element is selected then just use the debugger.